# How to call an activity's onResume method from a Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, onresume

I have an activity named GameTray where drawings carried are out. I have a ScreenReceiver which extends BroadcastReceiver, this is for detecting screen lock and phone lock. I want to save the datas while a screen lock occurs in the GameTray activity. onResume method of GameTray contains all the saving things. So I have a doubt, How can I call the onResume method method of GameTray activity in the ScreenReceiver class while overriding onReceive method? Am attaching the source for ScreenReciever here. Thanks in advance

public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
      if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))
      {    
           // Log.v("$$$$$$", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_OFF");
            // onPause() will be called.


      }
      else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
      {
           // Log.v("$$$$$$", "In Method:  ACTION_SCREEN_ON");
            //  HERE I WANT TO CALL THE ONRESUME METHOD OF THE ACTIVITY GAMETRAY.


      }
      else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT))
      {
          //  HERE I WANT TO CALL THE ONRESUME METHOD OF THE ACTIVITY GAMETRAY.
      }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> onResume method of GameTray contains all the saving things.

`onResume()` is a method that is part of an Activity life cycle, and it is called when the Activity comes to foreground, if you want to call it, you should start/resume the activity.

But why not create a separate class, or method, that will do all the saving things and be called in `onResume()` as well as in `onReceive()`.

Comment: dynamic changes are happening in GameTray. I have to save all those while it is resuming